# What happens when a Macbook overheats?

Tags: mac, macbook, overheating

I have an Apple Macbook on which I am running Trisquel GNU/Linux (similar distro to Ubuntu). I am experiencing some problems that I suspect may be related to the laptop overheating and I am wondering: what is the expected behavior when a Macbook overheats?

What I'm really looking for is an answer in the form of a sequential list of expected events, as the temperature increases.

Obviously, one of the first 'events' would be the fan rpm increasing. CPU throttling is something I would expect to occur at some point. I expect one of the last things to happen would be for the whole machine to trip a thermal cutout and reboot (which I have experienced). But, are there any other things that might be expected to happen in-between?

If anyone could provide approximate temperatures with this list of events, that would be even more helpful. Also, would any of this behavior be expected to change if I am running Linux, as opposed to Mac OS X?

Comment: The expected sequence of events is that the fans would spin faster & faster until equilibrium is maintained. Anything else is a fault. If you're not running macOS, that 'fault' could be poor co-ordination between the guest OS & the hardware.

Comment: @Tetsujin then let's say I put the laptop in an oven and gradually increase the temperature. What would happen as I go beyond the point where the fan speed is maxed-out? Perhaps I should re-phrase my question?

Comment: Results would be random. Under control of macOS, kernel-task would be pre-empting the cooling decision & eating more cycles than the machine actually possesses - in effect halting all other activity until the 'fake' CPU load resulted in the fans returning temps to equilibrium. If you force higher temperatures than that, then roll a dice to see what hardware fails first; there's no road-map for that.